# How to ignore new line characters with quotes in csv file for creating Hive External Table?

Tags: r, regex, csv, unix, hive

As part of huge data migration of R datasets , I am creating Hive External Tables. I do following using R program.
read all rds/sas files in R --> Create csv --> Upload to hdfs --> Create Hive external Table

**Issue:** There are new characters in some field values inside quotes because of which my source dataset has less rows and hive table shows more rows as some records are moving to next new lines.
Refer below for sample record.

CSV file in Excel shows data as below:
[image]

Notepad++ show as below:
[image]

**Question:**  How to ignore/remove ONLY new line characters inside quotes and not in the end of line, Using R program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds more like a problem with Hive, I'm not familiar with it, but it seems it should support newlines inside fields.

You can do that before saving to csv:

```
# Example data.frame
DF <- data.frame(1, "aaa", "bb\nb")


library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_remove_all(.x, "\n"))) %>%
  write_csv("test.csv")
```

Or the base R equivalent:

```
for(col in names(DF)){
  DF[[col]] <- gsub("\n", "", DF[[col]])
}
```

Comment: I think this will remove all "\n" but  I only want to remove the ones inside quotes and not in the end of line, as end of line "\n" are need to identify new lines or end of line.

Comment: If you do it on the data.frame *before* writing the csv, there is no end of line. That will only be done inside the fields. Once you call `wite.csv()` or `write_csv()`, the fields get enclosed by quotes, glued together with commas, and newlines get added as appropriate.